# what is the real understanding behind this use of quotations " '+movie['x']+' "?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have supposed to use this value to pass inside the function. but this worked after i used this method of using quotations. what would be the meaning of this 
**" ' + some value + ' "**

Comment: You should show us more of the code

Comment: These days, `\`blah blah blah "${movie['x']}" blah blah blah\` ` would probably be better. At least partly because it's less likely to prompt questions like this. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the following code example:

```
var myNumber = 1;

var myString = 'My number is: ' + myNumber + '!';

alert(myString);
```

This will alert `My number is: 1!`.

You're passing a `variable` into the string, identified by the `"` or `'` characters in JavaScript.

As cHao mentioned, using `string interpolation` is a better pattern nowadays as it's cleaner and easier to read.

So the code block above would become:

```
var myNumber = 1;

var myString = `My number is: ${myNumber}!`;

alert(myString);
```

Note that the quotes used to identify `myString` have changed from quote marks to back ticks, and you reference `myNumber` by using `${myNumber}` inside the string without needing to escape the string temporarily using `+ myNumber +`.